# Jquery Mobile scrolling and header issue in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova

I am implementing app using Phonegap and JQuery Mobile, that app working Perfectly in Android, but in iOS problem with single finger scrolling and header footer issues.
Firstly, when I add this code I lose single finger scrolling. The headers seem to be fixed in place, How can I make it so that the header + footer don't move when I scroll?

```
 body {
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;    
 }
```

How do I prevent header and footer scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the viewport as follow:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

From the default i've remove the height.

Then add in your **config.xml**:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

If you want you can limit it to iOS:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
</platform>
```

Comment: I modified with above code and tested but not working getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to explicitly set the size of the div that you want to be independently scrollable.  This has to occur after the page has been created.  Something like:

```
    // sizes the div for independent scrolling
    var divRect  = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

    myDiv.style.height = document.body.clientHeight-divRect.top +"px";
```